# Python regex catch two kind of comment

Tags: python, regex

Exemple :

```
a = "bzzzzzz <!-- blabla --> blibli * bloblo * blublu"
```

I want to catch the first comment. A comment may be

```
(<!-- .* -->) or (\* .* \*)
```

That is ok :

```
re.search("<!--(?P<comment> .* )-->",a).group(1)
```

Also that :

```
re.search("\*(?P<comment> .* )\*",a).group(1)
```

But if i want one or the other in comment, i have tried something like :

```
re.search("(<!--(?P<comment> .* )-->|\*(?P<comment> .* )\*)",a).group(1)
```

But it does't work

Thanks

Comment: BTW, your regexs are greedy and would fail on something like `<!-- first comment --> real material <!-- second comment -->`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try conditional expression:

```
>>> for m in re.finditer(r"(?:(<!--)|(\*))(?P<comment> .*? )(?(1)-->)(?(2)\*)", a):
...   print m.group('comment')
...
 blabla
 bloblo
```

Answer (score 1):

As Gurney pointed out, you have two captures with the same name. Since you're not actually using the name, just leave that out.

Also, the `r""` raw string notation is a good habit.

Oh, and a third thing: you're grabbing the wrong index. `0` is the whole match, `1` is the whole "either-or" block, and `2` will be the inner capture that was successful.

```
re.search(r"(<!--( .* )-->|\*( .* )\*)",a).group(2)
```

Comment: There can never be an index 3 with this regex.

Answer (score 1):

the exception you get in the "doesn't work" part is quite explicit about what is wrong:

```
sre_constants.error: redefinition of group name 'comment' as group 3; was group 2
```

both groups have the same name: just rename the second one

```
>>> re.search("(<!--(?P<comment> .* )-->|\*(?P<comment2> .* )\*)",a).group(1)
'<!-- blabla -->'
>>> re.search("(<!--(?P<comment> .* )-->|\*(?P<comment2> .* )\*)",a).groups()
('<!-- blabla -->', ' blabla ', None)
>>> re.findall("(<!--(?P<comment> .* )-->|\*(?P<comment2> .* )\*)",a)
[('<!-- blabla -->', ' blabla ', ''), ('* bloblo *', '', ' bloblo ')]
```

Answer (score 0):

`re.findall` might be a better fit for this:

```
import re

# Keep your regex simple. You'll thank yourself a year from now. Note that
# this doesn't include the surround spaces. It also uses non-greedy matching
# so that you can embed multiple comments on the same line, and it doesn't
# break on strings like '<!-- first comment --> fragment -->'.
pattern = re.compile(r"(?:<!-- (.*?) -->|\* (.*?) \*)")

inputstring = 'bzzzzzz <!-- blabla --> blibli * bloblo * blublu foo ' \
              '<!-- another comment --> goes here'

# Now use re.findall to search the string. Each match will return a tuple
# with two elements: one for each of the groups in the regex above. Pick the
# non-blank one. This works even when both groups are empty; you just get an
# empty string.
results = [first or second for first, second in pattern.findall(inputstring)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could go 1 of 2 ways (if supported by Python) -

1: Branch reset (?|pattern|pattern|...)
`(?|<!--( .*? )-->|\*( .*? )\*)/` capture group 1 always contains the comment text

2: Conditional expression (?(condition)yes-pattern|no-pattern)
`(?:(<!--)|\*)(?P<comment> .*? )(?(1)-->|\*)` here the condition is did we capt grp1

Modifiers `sg` single line and global